# sort items by date joined in tableview JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a tableview which there are some items in it with `date joined`, `date joined` form is `dd nameOfMonth, yyy`, how can i sort my items by `date joined`?

Here is the part of code for my item class:

```
    public static class Person1 {

    private StringProperty firstName;
    private StringProperty joined;

    public Person1(String firstName, String joined) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.joined = new SimpleStringProperty(joined);
    }
    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public StringProperty joinedProperty(){
        return joined;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you able to change the "joined" to Date property?

Comment: @UlukBiy I did not find `date property`

Comment: You wrap any Object in ObjectProperty: `ObjectProperty<Date> dateProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<>();`

Comment: can you help me how to declare it in constructor? it returns incompatible error

Comment: First define `private ObjectProperty<Date> dateProperty;` then in costructor `this.dateProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(joined);` where joined is `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @UlukBiy I did that but I get
    error: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for SimpleObjectProperty<>
            this.dateProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(joined);
    reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
      equality constraints: Date
      lower bounds: String
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class SimpleObjectProperty

Comment: Not SimpleObjectProperty<>  but ObjectProperty<Date>. Don't forget to put Date.

Comment: @UlukBiy now I get incompatible error:String cannot be converted to Date